# Excel - VBA Finding max variable after loop

Tags: excel, vba, variables, max

I am trying to have the max of 2 or 3 different variables (variants). They are all dates.
I have the code below, but I believe, I am doing something quite wrong.
Could you people help me?
Here is the code;

```
Dim QA As Integer: QA = 0    
For Each j_WS In Array(WS_1, WS_2, WS3) 

Select Case QA 
Case 0: j = 1 
Case 1: j = 2 
Case 2: j = 3 
End Select 

o = 14 + j * 3 
Dim WA1 As Variant 
Dim WA2 As Variant 
Dim WA3 As Variant 
Gorev = Cells(p, o).Address 
SlideNo = Cells(p, 34).Address 
Egitim_Adi = Cells(2, 3).Address 
Dim Satir_bul As Variant 


If Not IsError(Satir_bul) Then 
    Satir_bul = Worksheets(WS_All).Evaluate("=Match(" & Egitim_Adi & "&" & SlideNo & "&" & Gorev & ", '" & j_WS & "'!A:A&'" & j_WS & "'!B:B&'" & j_WS & "'!C:C, 0)") 
Else 
    WA1 = "" 
    WA2 = "" 
    WA3 = "" 
End If 


If j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then 
    WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value 
Else: WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value 
    If j = 2 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then 
        WA2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value 
    Else: WA2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value 
        If j = 3 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then 
            WA3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value 
        Else: WA3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value 


        End If 
    End If 
End If 


QA = QA + 1 
Next j_WS 


If WA1 > WA2 And WA1 > WA3 Then 
    MAX_DATE = WA1 
Else 
    If WA2 > WA3 And WA2 > WA1 Then 
        MAX_DATE = WA2 
    Else 
        If WA3 > WA2 And WA3 > WA1 Then 
            MAX_DATE = WA3 
        Else 
            MAX_DATE = "" 
        End If 
    End If 
End If 


Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 26).Value = MAX_DATE 


Next p
```

As you can see, almost everything is a predefined integer or something like that and WA1, WA2 and WA3 are all dates and I want MAX_DATE to be date too.

WA1, WA2 and WA3 doesn't come correct within loops. WA1 comes correct at first loop, WA2 comes correct at second loop and so on but for example at the second loop, WA1 comes empty. And because of this, MAX_DATE value is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare these variables as `Date`. Then the compilier will know how to compare them using `<` operator. Here's the code:

```
Dim d1, d2, d3 As Date

d1 = "06-01-2017"
d2 = "05-01-2018"
d3 = "01-01-1900" 'This can be some default value, you can't pass here empty string ("")

If d1 > d2 Then
    MsgBox ("a")
Else
    MsgBox ("b")
End If
```

If you use `Date` instead of `Variant` the message will be `b` and `a` otherwise.

As you need to pass some default values, see my proposition in the code. It won't affect your maximum, since is rather "low-value" date :)

Comment: Actually, the date type is not my main problem in here. The main problem is that after the first loop, MAX_DATE doesn't reset itself properly. It stuck with the first value I believe.

Comment: Because it's OUTSIDE the loop.

Comment: But it should be outside the WA loop, because it depends on 3 different WA values.

Comment: So it will be calculated only once, after the loop. It won't change value.

Comment: Yes, but it should recalculate and change after the first "p" loop. But it stucks at the first value. :(

Comment: Try to debug your code and see if `WA...` variables are changing.

Comment: WA is changing but this part doesn't change I'm afraid: `If WS_1 <> "" And WA1 <> "" And WS_2 <> "" And WA2 <> "" And WS_3 <> "" And WA3 = "" Or WS_1 <> "" And WA1 <> "" And WS_2 <> "" And WA2 = "" And WS_3 = "" Or WS_1 <> "" And WA1 = "" And WS_2 = "" And WS_3 = "" Then
    MAX_DATE = "" `